# Use Prism EventAggregator like the old CAB Event system with string event names

Tags: c#, string, prism, cab, eventaggregator

I see Prism`s eventaggregator always and only used with GetEvent which is very odd. I am used to the old CAB event system - now using Mediator implementation from Marlon Grech - where I have defined string constants that way I do not have to create extra classes to fire/wrap my data if its a simple int or value type.

```
[MediatorMessageSink(MediatorMessages.AddSchoolclass, ParameterType = typeof(int))]
        public void OnSchoolclassAdded(int schoolclassId)
        {
            // do stuff with schoolclassId
        }
```

How can I do the same with the eventaggregator from Prismn

Comment: With CAB attribute approach, I can set the same method to subscribe to multiple different events. Wish Prism has this..

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a single event class to use for all of your aggregate events, and pass a string as it's payload, but I wouldn't really recommend that approach. Prism developers would find it very confusing.

The Event Aggregator uses a different architecture than the old CAM. I wasn't happy either about the need for an event object when I made the change. But I've since been sold on the approach--the event object is basically a one-liner that I generate using a ReSharper template. The reason I like it so much is that it gives me a place to put any logic I might need to go along with the event.

Comment: Actually, it's rather intelligent. A well-designed application is like a Swiss watch, with each class acting as a gear in the overall assembly. Each class does one thing well, and they all collaborate to perform the work required. Far less brittle, and more easily maintained, than the old monolithic style of programming.

Comment: For the swiss watch/knife your are right. Each tool has its purpose. The question for me at the moment is what makes me faster developing.

Comment: let me ask you one last thing about the CAB event system vs prism event aggregator: WITH CAB I always had to REGISTER for a certain string/dattype BEFORE an OnMethod was executed if the messenger did a send/notify. Did this improve with prism event aggregator? Actually I ask myself how to send data to a Window I open because the ViewModel behind the Window is created AFTER the data is fired... so the OnMethod is never executed.

Comment: I do my windows a little differently. My windows get everything from the VM; if they need to take action when they open, I have the window subscribe to its own DataContextChanged event. The event fires when the VM is set, triggering an event handler in the window. The event handler does whatever is needed, getting its data from the VM.